# Location of complex roots of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial function in $x\in\mathbb{C}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose for a fixed $y=y_0$, the complex roots of the equation 
\begin{align}
f(x,y_0)=0 \tag{1}
\end{align}
are located strictly inside a ball $B(c,r)$, centered at $x=c$ with radius $r$. I would like to prove that "there exists a sufficiently small $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the complex roots of the equation 
\begin{align}
f(x,y_0+\epsilon)=0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
are also located strictly inside the ball $B(c,r)$, i.e., the same ball. Here we assume that (1) and (2) have the same total number of solutions."

The result seems obvious because $f$ is a continuous function. I was wondering what is a rigorous way to prove this fact.

Thank you, in advance, for your responses and comments.

Comment: What about Rouche's theorem?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know much about complex analysis and this theorem. Could you please add more details?

Comment: This is not true without additional hypotheses--for instance, consider $f(x,y)=xy+1$ and $y_0=0$.

Comment: You are right. I will update the question to emphasize that $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,y+\epsilon)$ have the same number of zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a consequence of [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem): 
$$
\min \{ |f(x, y_0)| : |x-c| = r \}
$$
is strictly positive, and
$$
f(x, y_0 + \epsilon) \to f(x, y_0) \text{ for } \epsilon \to 0
$$
uniformly on the compact circle $|x-c| = r$. It follows that
$$
 |f(x, y_0 + \epsilon)- f(x, y_0)| < |f(x, y_0)|
$$
for $|x-c| = r$ and sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

Then Rouché's theorem states that $f(x, y_0 + \epsilon)$ and $f(x, y_0)$ have the same number of zeros (counted with multiplicities) in $|x-c| < r$.

Now, if $f(x, y_0)$ and $f(x, y_0 + \epsilon)$ have the *same degree* (as polynomials in $x$) then it follows that all zeros of $f(x, y_0 + \epsilon)$  are in $|x-c| < r$.

Otherwise this is not necessarily true: Consider
$$
 f(x, y) = x - y x^2 \, , \, y_0 = 0 \, .
$$
Then $f(x, 0)$ has a single zero in $|x| < 1$, but for all $0 < \epsilon < 1$ has
$$
 f(x, \epsilon) = x (1- \epsilon x)
$$
and “additional” zero outside of the unit disk.

Comment: If all roots are *distinct* then it also follows from the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. This is very interesting!

Comment: @ Martin R just a quick question: why do we have $|f(x,y_0+\epsilon)-f(x,y_0)|<|f(x,y_0)|$?

Comment: @Arthur: The right-hand side has a positive minimum (because it is not zero), and the left-hand side converges to zero if $\epsilon \to 0$, uniformly on the circle.

Comment: Oh...I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Note though that this does not imply all zeroes of $f(x,y_0+\epsilon)$ are inside the ball, unless you know that $f(x,y_0+\epsilon)$ has the same total number of zeroes as $f(x,y_0)$.  That's not necessarily true!

Comment: @EricWofsey: You are right. I (perhaps wrongly) assumed all polynomials $f(\cdot, y)$ have the same degree, independent of $y$. If that is not the case then I'll have to update the answer.